# Time Series Classification with Unequal Time Between Events and Number

Tags: time-series, classification, mixed-model, time-varying-covariate, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a problem where I'd like to predict whether a customer is going to convert. I have event data for these customers over time and the histogram for time to conversion follows a 1/x pattern where most of the conversions happen closer to time t = 0 and tail off. It is also worth noting that conversions are the minority class here.

What I have looked at so far is essentially constructing a dataset where a row is a customer and conversion is essentially defined as "converts in the next month". Normally in a simple churn modeling case, you might pick a point in time, look at all customers at that point in time, construct features, predict whether they churn the following month, but because my positive class is infrequent, if I was to pick an arbitrary point in time, I'd greatly reduce the number of positive samples since they've happened over the course of years.

I'm trying to use information pertaining to all of my positive samples. For converting customers I'm taking the three months (somewhat arbitrary right now though could be refined) preceding conversion and aggregating counts of various events to create features. For non-converting customers, I run into the issue of "when am I looking at them?". I've toyed around with randomly sampling points in time and setting a fixed time for non-converters to generate aggregate features from, but I'm concerned about the time component here.

A counter-example I keep coming back to is: given a fixed time (say when the customer is 3 months old) for non-converters, suppose all customers look exactly the same at time period 1, but diverge from that point. Well my converting events, which tend to convert quickly will consider this event, but the non-converter events won't, which falsely weights this event in the model inflating results and eliminating the interpretation of a "probability" coming out of the model. Similarly, during predictions, we will see many customers who do this period 1 event, but don't necessarily convert while the model may be extremely biased to say they will, indicating the impact of "sampling time" for my negative samples.

I've thought about mixed models here as well, but honestly I'm just a bit stuck and would appreciate any direction someone could provide in crystallizing this problem. It feels like a slight variation of a sliding box churn model, but because I want to use all of my positive samples the time component seems to be throwing things off.

Comment: Just an idea: Could you use a survival model? Defining survival as **not converting**?

Comment: How would I be able to handle time-varying covariates? For example, at t=1 a record may have interacted once, but at t=5, they may have interacted 10 times. I'm currently deriving features based on a rolling time window, but I wouldn't be sure how to fit that into a classic survival model where features change over time.